# Spring JPA how to skip Foreign Key Constraint violation check

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

Is there a way to Skip Foreign Constraint check in Spring JPA.
In SQL ALTER TABLE TableName NOCHECK CONSTRAINT ForeignKeyName. How to achieve this programmatically using Spring JPA

I am working on a Sync tool using SpringBoot, Spring data JPA which copies data from one DB to Other and using Spring JPA, the tables in the schema have two many foreign key constraints and adding the mappings in all the entity classes is proving to be cumbersome. Any suggestion around skipping the constraint check and in general for the approach is appreciated.

I understand the consequence of data integrity, by removing the constraint check.

Answer (score 0):

There is no special JPA way to do this, but you can simply use SQL.

Depending on if you want to do the change just for the sync process or always you'd put the statement either in the creation scripts of the database or you execute it using [`EntityManager.createNativeQueryenter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#createNativeQuery-java.lang.String-)